# Is the memory address provided by Python’s id() method absolute or relative to some session?

Tags: python, memory, ctypes, ram, cpython

**TO THE POINT VERSION (tldr):**
Can I use id() in Python to get the location of a variable in memory, restart my computer, and then use that same id to verify if the data is still stored there? Or is id() a ‘Python-only’/session dependent value?

—————————————————

**DETAILED VERSION:**

*Background:*

I’m storing an integer in a variable x, then using Phthon’s id() method to get the location in memory. I’m verifying the value in that location matches what I set to x using ctypes and the id returned from id().

What I need to do is remove the variable from RAM (physically remove it so it no longer exists and could never be recovered). I know that makes it sound like I’m doing something sketchy, but I promise that is not the case.

I’ve tried:

del x

x = None

But when I run ctypes using the id I still get the value initially set to x.

*Potential Solution:*

Since messing around with the physical RAM is above my skill level, my plan is to save the value id() returns in a text file, restart my computer (theoretically clearing RAM) and then use another script to verify if x’s pre-resart location in memory holds an integer between 0-255. If it does not, then continue with the program.

*Problem/Question:*

Does the value I get from Python’s id() method give an absolute address in memory that I can check after restart (or using a different programming language) or is that value relative to a Python session?

I tried looking at CPython on GitHub, but I couldn’t find the id() method to see what is goin on under the hood.

Comment: "Still stored there"? How can it be?

Comment: @roganjosh If I knew why it was still showing up in RAM I wouldn't be here asking a question.

Comment: I think you're being thrown by the python integer cache, otherwise I'm totally lost on what you're asking.

Comment: Restarting your computer erases **all** memory contents. There is absolutely no need to go and try and erase that data from memory again after a reboot.

Comment: Have you verified that the integer object has a reference count of 0? `del x` only removes that one reference (`x = None` after `del x` is entirely redundant, there is no point in doing that). Python objects are removed only when their reference count drops to 0. If you have a ctypes reference to the object then the reference count is **not yet 0**.

Comment: Next, a modern OS **protects** per-process memory from other processes. Another process can't just go and read that memory. If it could, then things like encryption would be impossible. You are trying to solve a problem that doesn't exist here.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I keep getting mixed answers on if restarting a computer clears the ram. I've read posts that say it clears immediately, and others where someone says it can take minutes to fully clear ram of all electrons. Do you know which is true?

Comment: @user1165664: see [Wipe RAM on shut down to prevent Cold Boot Attack](//superuser.com/q/464297). If you are worried about memory security to this extend, then Python is the wrong language to implement such a sensitive system in. Look at a system programming language instead, something like Rust, not C.

Answer (score 2):

The correspondence of the output of `id()` to the memory address is an [implementation detail](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id) of CPython.  It does not apply to other python implementations (such as as Jython or Pypy) and it may not apply to future releases of CPython.  You should not depend on this behaviour.